# How do I make Winston globally available in Sails.js application?

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging, sails.js, winston

I have a Sails.js application and I would like to be able to use Winston along with Loggly to log messages. Right now, I have a service like this:

```
log: function(type, message, content) {
    // Require and configure Winston with Loggly
    const winston = require('winston');
    require('winston-loggly');

    winston.add(winston.transports.Loggly, {
        token       : ***,    // Hiding my real token
        subdomain   : ***,
        tags        : ['sails-web-service'],
        json        :true
    });

    // Attach context to the content
    var finalContent = { timestamp: Date.now(), pid: process.pid };
    for (var attribute in content) { finalContent[attribute] = content[attribute]; }

    // Send the log
    winston.log(type, message, finalContent);
}
```

I can call this service by doing something like: `LogService.log('info', 'Log in attempt', { email: req.body.email });`.

Ideally, I would just like to use Winston directly anywhere in the application like this: `winston.log('info', 'Log in attempt', { email: req.body.email });` without having to create a service OR having to require and configure Winston in every controller where I want to use it. How do I make it globally available?

Answer (score 1):

If you have it in `api/services` you dont need to initialize it each time. If you don't want to require modules each time you can do it like that. Move those lines

```
winston = require('winston')
require('winston-loggly')
```

to `config/bootstrap.js` and change it to:

```
sails.winston = require('winston');
sails.winston-loggly = require('winston-loggly');
```

and your service

```
log: function(type, message, content) {
   // Require and configure Winston with Loggly

    sails.winston.add(winston.transports.Loggly, {
        token       : ***,    // Hiding my real token
        subdomain   : ***,
        tags        : ['sails-web-service'],
        json        :true
    });

// Attach context to the content
    var finalContent = { timestamp: Date.now(), pid: process.pid };
    for (var attribute in content) { finalContent[attribute] = content[attribute]; }

    // Send the log
    sails.winston.log(type, message, finalContent);
}
```

---

You can try using [sails-hook-winston](https://github.com/Kikobeats/sails-hook-winston).

Library extends log, so its config goes to `config/log.js`. In your case it should look more like this:

```
transports: [
    {
        module: require('winston-loggly').Loggly,
        config: {
            token       : ***,    // Hiding my real token
            subdomain   : ***,
            tags        : ['sails-web-service'],
            json        :true
        }
    }
]
```